# "Bounty expired" email falsely states question is mine

Tags: bug, bounties

I took out a bounty on another user's question: [Why is the following command inconsistent in my repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460068/why-is-the-following-command-inconsistent-in-my-repository)

After the bounty period expired, I received a reminder email containing the following message (emphasis mine):

> Thanks for putting a bounty on **your question**. It looks like there are
>   still no answers yet. You should consider improving **your question** to
>   attract more answers. Could you:
>
> - add more text describing the problem?
> - add or change the tags?
> - update the title to more accurately reflect the issue?

---

Should a different message go out when the bounty is taken out by a third party?